# delete execution log other than recent 2 function set (mastersp_id, exec_id) logs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to create a stored procedure that will purge the data in execution log table (condition: all logs other than recent 2 should be deleted)

create table and insert data:

```
create table tbltest12 (mastersp_id int, exec_id int, [procedure] 
    varchar(50), [status] varchar(20), starttime DATETIME DEFAULT 
    GETDATE(), endtime DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE())   
insert into tbltest12 values 
(1,1,'proc a', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,1,'proc b', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,1,'proc c', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2,1,'proc y', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2,1,'proc z', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,2,'proc a', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,2,'proc b', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,2,'proc c', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2,2,'proc y', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2,2,'proc z', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2,3,'proc y', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2,3,'proc z', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,3,'proc a', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,3,'proc b', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(1,3,'proc c', 'success', GETDATE(), GETDATE())
```

Below data set is left after deletion of data.

```
    mastersp_id exec_id procedure   status  starttime           endtime
    1               2   proc a      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    1               2   proc b      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    1               2   proc c      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    2               2   proc y      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    2               2   proc z      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    2               3   proc y      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    2               3   proc z      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    1               3   proc a      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    1               3   proc b      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
    1               3   proc c      success 02-09-2019 15:03    02-09-2019 15:03
```

Comment: You've done a great gob posting sample data and desired results, but not so much with regards you showing your own efforts. Please [edit] your question to include your current attempt and what went wrong with it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : i have tried hard, but not able to get to any viable solution :(

Comment: So you want to only keep two records for each procedure, where the start dates are the highest, is that correct?

Comment: @ZoharPeled : No. I want to keep records of the 2 most recent exec ids for both stored procedures (mastersp_id : 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to to use a common table expression with a column based on `Dense_rank` and delete directly from the cte:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT mastersp_id, exec_id, [procedure], [status], starttime, endtime,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY mastersp_id ORDER BY exec_id DESC) As Rn
    FROM tbltest12
)

DELETE 
FROM CTE
WHERE Rn > 2
```

Comment: this isn't giving the desired output.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Using `Dense_rank` instead of `row_number` should provide your requested results.